# Maximizing form on secondary screen with different resolution?

Tags: c#, winforms, multiple-monitors, maximize

I am developping a simple windows application (in C#) and I want it to display a form that is maximized in my second monitor. To do so, I am doing the following on the "Load" event of the form:

```
private void FormTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.Location = screens[1].WorkingArea.Location;
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;                    
    }
```

The problem I have is that when I execute this, the form only takes part of the screen. My primary screen has a resolution of 1024x768 and my secondary screen has a resolution of 1920x1080, and it seems that the form is taking the size of the primary screen in my secondary screen.

Also, I have a button that runs the following code to maximize the screen or turn it back to normal:

```
private void ChangeSize() {
    if (this.WindowState == System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized)
    {
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
    }
    else
    {
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
}
```

When I click on the button twice (first to de-maximize the form, and then to maximize it again) the form does cover the entire secondary screen perfectly, but if I try to just run that function in code twice (for the sake of testing) right after the code in "FormTest_Load", the screen will still not cover correctly the entire screen.

I am probably making a noob mistake here but I have struggled with this for some time, so I would really appreciate if anyone can shed some light on what is wrong with my code.

Comment: The Load event is too late, by then Winforms has already processed the WM_GETMINMAXINFO message.  Move the code into the constructor.

Comment: ...or, if you're doing this elsewhere, first set the `Location`, then `BorderStyle`, then `WindowState`, then `Refresh()` (if you're drawing a custom Border you'll notice). It's also quite better if you make your app DpiAware , since you might get wrong (adjusted) measures otherwise.

Comment: Controls anchored in the middle of the ClientArea may resize to disproportionate bounds.

Comment: Thank you both for your ideas, but unfortunately I'm still having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, only the resolution of the second monitor is smaller than the first.
The only solution I have found is through using WinAPI:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    protected static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
    protected static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP = new IntPtr(0);
    protected const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    
    private void FormTest_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {
            Size size = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Size;
    
            if (!Size.Equals(size))
            {
                SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, size.Width, size.Height, SWP_NOMOVE);
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to get the same result as you describe (changing resolutions, etc), but all works fine in my computer and screens. May be... what is exactly the variable `screens`? I've assumed that is `Screen.AllScreens`, like this:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;
        int screenNumber = 1;

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.Location = screens[screenNumber].WorkingArea.Location;
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
```

As I said, it works fine for me.
Also, you can check the screen settings of your computer: is the size of text and apps set to `100% (recommended value)`?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I forgot to add the line "Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;" in my first post (I will edit my first post). The text and apps are set to 100%, yes. It is strange indeed...